# Simple example for logging text in expecto test

Tags: f#, expecto, logary

I'm trying to write some logs in an Expecto test, however I can't figure out how to get anything to be logged. Is there a very simple example of this somewhere? Currently I have:

```ml
module Test

open Expecto
open Expecto.Logging
open Expecto.Logging.Message
open Hopac
open Logary.Configuration
open Logary.Adapters.Facade
open Logary.Targets

[<Tests>]
let tests =
  test "A simple test" {
    let logger = Log.create "asdf.qwer"

    let one = 1
    ignore (logger.logWithAck Debug (eventX "asdf"))
    Expect.equal one 1 "Should equals 1"
  }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let logary =
    Config.create "MyProject.Tests" "localhost"
    |> Config.targets [ LiterateConsole.create LiterateConsole.empty "console" ]
    |> Config.processing (Events.events |> Events.sink ["console";])
    |> Config.build
    |> run
  LogaryFacadeAdapter.initialise<Expecto.Logging.Logger> logary


  // Invoke Expecto:
  runTestsInAssemblyWithCLIArgs [] argv
```

Comment: were you running it as `dotnet test` or running the test assembly another way?